# Get large friend list profile pictures from LinkedIn using SocialAuth library

Tags: android, linkedin-api, socialauth

I'm currently using the SocialAuth library to log into various social medias in my app, but i've run into an issue with LinkedIn.

I can easily get the profile image URL and use it to grab the image and put into an ImageView, but the image i get is 80x80 pixels, which is not ideal.

With both Facebook and Twitter, there was a distinction in the URL (small, normal, large) of some sort, where i could substring/replace to get the large image. But this option is not available for LinkedIn from the URLs i have available.

Is there some method that i'm missing, or is it simply not possible at the moment?

Answer (score 1):

MAybe using [ASNE library](https://github.com/gorbin/ASNE) make your life easier?
Just add dependency to your project:

```
dependencies {
...
    compile 'com.github.asne:asne-facebook:0.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.asne:asne-twitter:0.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.asne:asne-linkedin:0.2.0'
...
}
```

setup and request any info like profile(with link and image `socialNetwork.requestCurrentPerson();`) or friends(just  `socialNetwork.requestGetFriends();`)